# Unknown name "collapse" error when trying to format a pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a pivot table with the rows collapsed from the start. I am also trying to sort by the grand total for each row in column index 0.

I have tried inserting `"collapse": true` in areas where I think it should be but I get an error:

> "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "collapse" at 'requests[0].update_cells.rows.values[0].pivot_table.rows[1]': Cannot find field."

Below is my code:

```js
var request = {
  "updateCells": {
    "rows": {
      "values": [{
        "pivotTable": {
          "source": {
            "sheetId": dSheetID,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "startColumnIndex": 2,
            "endRowIndex": dRange,
            "endColumnIndex": 6
          },
          "rows": [
            //Organize Name
            {
              "sourceColumnOffset": 0,
              "showTotals": false,
              "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
            },
            //Organize Flowers
            {
              "sourceColumnOffset": 1,
              "showTotals": true,
              "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
            }
          ],
          "columns": [

          ],
          "values": [{
              "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
              "sourceColumnOffset": 2,
              "name": " "
            },
            {
              "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
              "sourceColumnOffset": 3,
              "name": "Total Points"
            }
          ],
          "valueLayout": "Vertical"
        }
      }]
    },
    "start": {
      "sheetId": leaderboardSheetID,
      "rowIndex": 1,
      "columnIndex": 1
    },
    "fields": "pivotTable"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to making this work. Just use `collapsed` instead of `collapse` (please notice the D at the end in the correct one). Additionally, please check the docs to [edit pivot tables](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables#edit_pivot_table_columns_and_rows) to see some explanations and examples. Feel free to leave a comment if you still have doubts.

Comment: Collapsed didn't work either. Maybe it is the location?  Here is where I think it should go:

`"rows": [
                    //Organize Name
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset": 0,
                      "showTotals": false,
                      "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                      "collapsed": true
                    },`

Comment: `collapsed` must be located inside `valueMetadata`, not `rows`. Please check the linked docs on my answer to see a real working example. The example shows the usage of `collapsed` in columns, but you can apply the same approach on rows instead.